# landing page with 2 options or 2 different sites

Tags: landing-page

I'm working on a software as a service platform to monitor remotely devices.
The project was targeted before to only aged care. And the website, landing page, reflects that.

The offering now expanded to include child care.

It is the same platform, but targeted to different users, where the app will look the same for the user, but the companion app is different for the patient.

My question is if is better to have 2 different landing pages, 2 URLs (example.com and example2.com), or have one landing page (example.com) where the user can select the solution, then gets redirected to that specific website (children.example.com or seniors.example.com)?

Comment: You don't need to choose. You can do AB testing and let the results tell you what's best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the landing page that let the user select the solution and redirect on that sub-website.

Why?
Simply because you show that your company have an ecosystem of services to your users.
I think that showing possible leads that your business have enough ressources to do multiple things in different field makes them think that you're successful (and thus, making them think you're good at what you're doing). This assumption is made based on Social Psychology Research.

Plus, it can be more flexible if your company wants to develop in other field as well, they'll already get the website that fit (just adding a sub-website) and your users won't be lost if they come back later on your website!

Again, another advantage of this solution is that actual happy users (from one of your market target) knowing people from your secondary market target can refer your services and your company to people they know. Thus, making referal marketing a possibility of development for your company. (Old people knows young people that have children and that can be interested in your services)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for one landing page in order to be more flexible for future services, and will actually show that the company offers larger scope of services, which is always a plus in the eye of customers.